# Validation summary in Kendo Ui inline grid

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there anyway to use validation summary inline kendo grid. please advise. if any link that i could follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use a validation summary with Kendo UI grid.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to use a validation summary in KendoUI grid

Just make ul element above your grid like

```
<ul class="errorMessages"></ul>
```

Then in the edit function of the grid get a reference to the validator and add a click event to the update button

```
 edit : function(e) {
 var myValidator = e.sender.editable.validatable
  e.container.find('.k-grid-update').click(function() {
                 if (!myValidator.validate()) {
                      displayErrors(myValidator)
                 }
            });
}
```

Then the displayErrors function  note I use a custom data attribute to make a friendly name for an input ie instead of using the id="firstName" I add data-myfriendly="First Name" you can use whatever you want title, id, name ect

```
 function displayErrors(validator) {
        var errorList = $('ul.errorMessages');
        errorList.empty();
        var myerrors = validator._errors;
        var count = 0;
        $.each(myerrors, function(field, errmsg) {
            //Set focus on first field
            if (count === 0) {
                $('#' + field).focus();
                count++;
            }
            //Set css
            $('#' + field).css({
                'box-shadow' : '0 0 5px #d45252',
                'border-color' : '#b03535'
            });
            var titlerrmsg = $('#' + field).attr("title");
            var friendly = $('#' + field).attr("data-myfriendly");
            errorList.append('<li><span>' + friendly + ' is</span> ' + titlerrmsg + '</li>');
        });
        errorList.show();
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you for your response. I have tried your code recently, both what i got is the required message appear to be undefined. thank you